# How can I know what render engine a file is made for?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm an intern in a lab and they want to use blenderfiles for generating stimuli for a visual perception experiment. The previous intern got started, and now I need to finish. Because of how this experiment will be set up, we need files all made in the same engine. I know that you can see the engine on top of the screen, but I think she changed it sometimes to a different engine, and now I don't know the real engine anymore.

Comment: First off, check the materials if there are any. They are drastically different between the render engines.

Comment: By default, Blender keeps backup copies of the .blend files. They are named .blend1 .blend2 and so on, .blend1 being the most recent before the current. Check the directory where the current .blend is located, to see if there are any backups left.

Comment: Depending on your scene, someone with experience using the different engines might be able to answer your question based on looking at renders. For example, if there is speckly noise, it was probably with Cycles. Hard shadows probably means BI. Do you have some example renders you could add to your post?

Answer (score 1):

First, unless the previous person used an external engine, when the file is loaded, whichever file is being used for the blendfiles will be displayed. But more fundamentally, it would seem to me that all of the files just need to have the same engine, and you could reset any that don't conform to the desired norm.